# Silverlight WCF RIA Service select from SQL View vs SQL Table

Tags: wcf-ria-services, silverlight-5.0

I have arrived at this dilemma via a tortuous and frustrating route, but I'll start with where I am right now. For information I'm using VS2010, Silverlight 5 and the latest versions of the Silverlight and RIA Toolkits, SDKs etc.

I have a view in my database (it's actually now an indexed view, but that has made no difference to the behaviour). For testing purposes (and that includes testing my sanity) I have duplicated the view as a Table (ie identical column names and definitions), and inserted all the view rows into the table. So if I SELECT * from the view or the table in Query Analyzer, I get *identical* results. So far so good.

I create an EDF model in my Silverlight Business Application web project, including all objects.

I create a Domain Service based on the model, and it creates ContextTypes and metadata for both the View and the Table, and associated Query objects.

If I populate a Silverlight ListBox in my Silverlight project via the Table Query, it returns all the data in the table.

If I populate the same ListBox via the View Query, it returns one row only, always the first row in the collection, however it is ordered. In fact, if I delve into the inner workings via the debugger, when it executes the ObjectContext Query in the service, it returns a result set of the correct number of rows, but all the rows are identical! If I order ascending I get n copies of the first row, descending I get n copies of the last row.

Can anyone put me out of my misery here, and tell me why the View doesn't work?

Ade

Answer (score 2):

OK, well that was predictable - nearly every time I ask a question on a forum I stumble across the answer while I'm waiting for responses to flood in!

Despite having been through the metadata and model.designer files and made sure that all "view" and "table" class/method definitions etc were identical, it was still showing the exasperating difference in behaviour between view and table queries. So the problem just had to be caused by the database, right?

Sure enough, I hadn't noticed myself creating NOT NULL columns when I created the "identical" Table version of my view! Even though I was using a SELECT NEWID() to create a unique key column on the view, the database insisted that the ID column in the view was NULLABLE, and it was apparently this which was causing the problem.

To save some storage space I switched from using NEWID() to using ROW_NUMBER() to create my key column, but still had the "NULLABLE" property problem. SO I then changed it to

SELECT ISNULL(ROW_NUMBER() (OVER...) , -1)

for the ID column, and at last the column in the view was created NOT NULL! Even though neither NEWID() nor ROW_NUMBER() can ever generate NULL output, it seems you have to hold SQL Server's hand and reassure it by using the ISNULL operator before it will believe itself.

Having done this, deleted/recreated my model and service files, everything burst into glorious technicolour life without any manual additions of [Key()] properties or anything else. The problem had been with the database all along, and NOT with the Model/Service/Metadata definitions.

Hope this saves someone some time. Now all I need to do is work out why the original stored procedure method I started with two days ago doesn't work - but at least I now have a hint!

Ade